# How to compare previous key of an associative array with current key in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, compare, key

I want to echo the most common number from an array. I have one array and I want to compare the previous key with the current key of my array. How do I do that?

I have made two foreach loops:

```
$mostCommon = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['array'] as $key => $value) {
       foreach ($_SESSION['array'] as $key2 => $value2){
           $key++;
       }
       if(current key is higher than previous key){
           $mostCommon = $value;
       }
}
```

This is how I wan't to do it.

Comment: I don't see a connection between `common number` and comparing keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can save the previous key outside the loop.

**Example:**

```
$previousKey = null;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key > $previousKey){ //If current key is greater than last key

    }
    $previousKey = $key;
}
```

$highestKey will be set to the biggest key in that array.

Answer (score 0):

The most common number can be found using array_count_values.
The output of array_count_values is an associative array with key being the value, and value being the number of times it's in the array.
Sort the array with asort to preserve the keys.
Flip the array to get the value that is the most common and echo the last item.

```
$arr = [1,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,2,5,3,7];

$counts = array_count_values($arr);
asort($counts);
$flipped = array_flip($counts);
echo "most common number: " . end($flipped) . " is in the array " . end($counts) . " times";
//most common number: 3 is in the array 5 times
```

https://3v4l.org/qSD4J